# Scanner NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I made a program that asks for 3 integers to output type of triangle. Everything runs and compiled successfully, however, it seems the part where it asks the user to see if they want to loop it again, the online compiler outputs the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>           at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
>           at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
>           at Assignment5.main(Assignment5.java:56)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Assignment5 {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {


        for (int a = 0; a < Integer.MAX_VALUE; a++)
        {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x,y,z;

        System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle: ");


        x = userInput.nextInt();
        y = userInput.nextInt();
        z = userInput.nextInt();
        Tri isos = new Tri(x,y,z);
        Tri equal = new Tri(x,y,z);
        Tri scalene = new Tri(x,y,z);



          // check the equilateral triangle
          System.out.println(equal.toString() + " triangle:");


          if (equal.is_isosceles())
             System.out.println("\tIt is isosceles");
          else
             System.out.println("\tIt is not isosceles");

          if (equal.is_equilateral())
             System.out.println("\tIt is equilateral");
          else 
             System.out.println("\tIt is not a equilateral");

          if (equal.is_scalene())
             System.out.println("\tIt is scalene");
          else
             System.out.println("\tIt is not scalene");

          System.out.println("Would you like to enter values again? (y/n)" );

          String input = answer.next();   //Exception is thrown from here

          if (input.equals("y"))
          {
              System.out.println("ok");
          }
              else if(!input.equals("y"))
              {
                  System.out.println("Ok, bye.");
                  break;
              }

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is on the line 56? I am also wondering why would you need 2 Scanners.

Comment: line 56:
     String input = answer.next();
       
       if (input.equals("y"))
       {
        System.out.println("ok");
       }
       else if(!input.equals("y"))
       {
        System.out.println("Ok, bye.");
        break;
       }

Comment: Tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: try entering all integers on one line seperated by spaces

Comment: It runs for me, but when I submit into the online grading compiler for my school, I get that error.

Comment: @Aneesh Yeah. Same here. That's why I wasn't able to track the OPs problem here. Works perfectly fine. Even with nextLine()

Comment: Your best bet is to use a single scanner. Using two scanners on same stream can have unexpected side effects since a scanner can consume the stream meant for some other scanner

Answer (score 1):

[`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html):

> Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that
>   there are no more elements in the enumeration.

You're getting this exception because [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) **doesn't** read the new line character, which is the character when you press enter (`\n`), so in the next `for` iteration, you're trying to read it, which causes the exception.

One possible solution is to add `answer.nextLine()` right after `answer.next()` in order to *swallow* this extra `\n`.

---

Example of your code:

```
Iteration (a) |  input for scanner    |  Data for scanner
--------------+-----------------------+-------------------
      0       |   "Hello" (And enter) |       Hello
      1       |         \n            |      PROBLEM!
```

Comment: Where did you place it?

Comment: String input = answer.next();
  input = answer.nextLine();

Comment: Why are you still using two scanners ? Remove `Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);` and replace `String input = answer.next()` with `String input = userInput.next()`

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems that answer.next() does not actually have any value assigned to it
usually int name = answer.next() name is assigned what ever answer is. What i mean is that name cant be assigned a value because answer.next() doesn't have one.

At least this is my understanding. The alternative is the get rid of answer.next and use the other scanner.
actually an edit to this.

a scanner reads from files or the console. You have one scanner already (userInput) the second scanner isn't actually doing anything as well as it being an actual scanner, it doesn't have anything to read.
get rid of answer as a scanner, replace is with an int, String, double and have 
int answer = userInput.nextInt();
or
double answer = userInput.nextDouble();
or
String answer = userInput.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

As you said the code runs for you but doesn't when compiled and executed on an online compiler. The answer scanner is exhausted because it doesn't have any elements.

It's embarrassing but i once got the same error when compiling my code on an online compiler, it turned out i wasn't supplying input beforehand to the input section and was expecting the online compiler to ask for the input.

Since you are using two scanners to get input from console, try using the scanner userInput to take the input from a file instead. (It may vary for different online compilers, but there will be an option to provide input from file)